# Singleton java pattern

Tags: java

I can still instantiate by using constructor although in class definition it has been declared as private constructor??? Here is code snippet:

```
public class Singleton {

  private static Singleton instance;
  private String name;

  /* Private constructor prevents other classes from instantiating */
  private Singleton(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    // Optional code
  }

  /*
   * Static factory method that creates instance instead of constructor.
   * Synchronization helps to block any attempt to instantiate from simultaneous
   * thread hence break concept of singleton.
   * This method uses a technique known as lazy instantiation.
   */
  public static synchronized Singleton getInstance(String name) {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new Singleton(name);
    }
    return instance;
  }

  /* Override Object clone method to avoid cloning */
  @Override
  public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  /* Example of using singleton object */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Singleton a = new Singleton("Hoang");
    Singleton b = new Singleton("Shiha");
    System.out.println(a.getName());
    System.out.println(b.getName());
  }
```

Comment: Dude, put the time to post these things right and learn how to enter code samples. That stuff  is almost unreadable.

Comment: You can get code formatted as code by putting four spaces before each line. Or select it and press the `{}` button. See the [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page for more information.

Comment: You don't need to override clone(), it will throw an exception anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still instantiate it because your test main() method, being in the same class, has access to the private constructor: private means "only available to this class".

Put your test in another class, and you'll get what you expect.

Comment: You're welcome, we all make mistakes :-)   I see you're new to Stack Overflow, the normal etiquette if this has satisfactorily answered your questions is to "accept answer" to mark it as resolved - and give the responder some tasty karma points :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your test method is within the same class -> it has access to private members & methods.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081227/singleton-pattern) question for more info on the Singleton pattern in Java :)

Answer (score 1):

You are able to instantiate the singleton because you are doing it from a method inside the Singleton's class definition (hint, you can access private methods within the class that define them.

Try doing that from **outside** your Singleton, and it will fail. On another note, Singleton are typically defined as **final** (very rare that you legitimately need to extend a Singleton class).

---

On another note, one typically puts some sort of guard condition (.ie. throwing a UnsupportedOperationException) on the default (and ***private***) constructor to defend against accidental (or malicious attack) access to it via reflection.

```
  /* default constructor made private and defended against reflection access */
  private Singleton() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("naughty boy");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To be sure to instanciate it just once, you may use the Singleton Enum pattern:

```
public enum MySingleton {
    INSTANCE("My singleton name");

    private MySingleton(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

An enum is in some way a list of singletons sharing the same interface